# How to resolve 'autoReload feature is required to use this plugin' issue

Tags: postgresql, heroku, digital-ocean, strapi, digital-ocean-apps

can you help resolve this - I can’t add anything via strapi dashboard. I get “autoReload feature is required to use this plugin. Start your server with strapi develop” Thing is that I started the server with strapi develop

What I have done to resolve - I set the NODE_ENV environment variable to development via Apps -->Settings --> App-Level Environment Variables but the issue still persists.

Comment: How have you started the `Strapi` server? Did you run the `npm run develop` command?

Comment: I have faced the same issue but I stopped the server and run this command `npm run develop` works again without this warning.

Answer (score 0):

change start command to "strapi develop"